# Scrollbar in Tkinter inside Text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar

I have problem with set in Scrollbar inside Text widget in Tkinter. I know, that it's preferable to use grid to locate widgets but I want to set my widget in absolute location (x,y - red dot on GUI picture) with specified height and width.

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class NotebookDemo(Frame):

    def __init__(self):      
        Frame.__init__(self)       
        self.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Sample')
        self.master.geometry("650x550+100+50")
        self._initUI()

    def _initUI(self):
        self._createPanel()

    def _createPanel(self):

        # create frame inside top level frame
        panel = Frame(self)    
        panel.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # create the notebook
        nb = Notebook(panel)
        nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=2, pady=3)        
        self._FirstTab(nb)


    def _FirstTab(self, nb):

        # frame to hold content
        frame = Frame(nb)

        #textbox
        txtOutput = Text(frame, wrap = NONE, height = 17, width = 70)
        txtOutput.place(x=10, y=75)

        #button
        btnStart = Button(frame, text = 'Start', underline=0)
        btnStart.place(x=220, y=380)

        #scrollbar
        #vscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=txtOutput.yview)
        #txtOutput['yscroll'] = vscroll.set
        #vscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        #txtOutput.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

        #add to notebook (underline = index for short-cut character)
        nb.add(frame, text='TAB 1', underline=0, padding=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = NotebookDemo()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: GUI:]

If I uncomment this part of code (set Scrollbar):

```
vscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=txtOutput.yview)
txtOutput['yscroll'] = vscroll.set
vscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

My Scrollbar is located inside all window, not inside Text box:

[image]

But of course I want to have the Scrollbar inside the Text box widget (black border). 
If I use pack function to textbox:

```
txtOutput.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
```

text widget fill in the whole window...:

[image]

I really don't know how fix this problem.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

EDIT:

Of course I can use place method with Scrollbar too, but I can't change length of them, because it hasn't attribute length.

```
vscroll.place(x=573, y=75)
```

[image]

Comment: If you insist on using `place` for the text widget, why are you not also using it for the scrollbar? Are you aware that `place` has many options, including options to place one widget relative to another? If you are aware of them, have you tried them?

Comment: Of course I can use place method with Scrollbar too, but I can't change length of them, because it hasn't length attribute (or maybe has it?). I edited my post and attached image.

Comment: You can use `place` to set the width and height of elements. For example, the `height` attribute sets the height to an absolute height, the `relheight` attribute sets the height relative to some other widget.  You should spend some time reading the documentation. While I rarely recommend `place`, it's remarkably powerful when you make use of all of its features.

Comment: I read about Text widget's attributes: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm.  According to this spec it has only width attribute. If I try use height attribute, I get AttributeError: Scrollbar instance has no attribute 'height' or TclError: unknown option "-height"..

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. The attributes are for `place`.

Comment: Yeah, `place(height = ...)` works perfectly - I exactly looked for that! Thank you !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I rarely recommend `place`, it is quite powerful when you take advantage of the configuration options. For example, you can use `in_` to specify a widget that this widget is to be placed relative to. You can use `relx` to specify a relative x coordinate, and you can use `relheight` to specify a height.

In your case you can try something like this:

```
vscroll.place(in_=txtOutput, relx=1.0, relheight=1.0, bordermode="outside")
```

If you want the illusion that the scrollbar is embedded inside the text widget as is (or used to be) common on some platforms, I recommend placing the text widget and scrollbar in a frame.You can use `pack` to put the widgets in the frame, and continue to use `place` to place the combination anywhere you want.

For example:

```
txtFrame = Frame(frame, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
txtOutput = Text(txtFrame, wrap = NONE, height = 17, width = 70, borderwidth=0)
vscroll = Scrollbar(txtFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=txtOutput.yview)
txtOutput['yscroll'] = vscroll.set

vscroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
txtOutput.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

txtFrame.place(x=10, y=75)
```

Comment: I exactly looked for that, Thank you again !!

Comment: just what i needed.

Answer (score 3):

Different geometry managers like `place` and `pack` don't mix so well. I see four options for you:

### Use a parent frame

Create a new `Frame` that you `place` at the exact same position as you did with the text box. In this frame, you can use another geometry manager (I'd prefer `pack`) to make the layout appear as you want.

### Use ScrolledText

Use the `ScrolledText` Tkinter module to have the solution above in a premade form. Note that this widget doesn't use `ttk` so the scrollbar style does not really adapt to the OS' look. Just use `import ScrolledText` and replace the `Text` creation in your code with `ScrolledText.ScrolledText(...)`.

### Use place for the scrollbar

If you are using `place` for the text widget, use `place` for the scrollbar too. `place` has options that allow you to place a widget relative to another widget both in location and size (ie: you can place the scrollbar along the right edge of the text widget, and cause it to be exactly as tall as the text widget). [See Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41981244/3216660).

### Don't use place

Simple as that. Use `grid` or `pack` instead, unless you *really* need to use `place`.

Comment: The other option is to continue to use `place`, and also use `place` for the scrollbar.

Comment: @BryanOakley Of course, I missed the obvious... feel free to edit this option in, I don't know too much about that.

Comment: Thank for your options :) I will choose one of them and try to implement.