# How to move the scrollbar to inside the text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code

```
from tkinter import *

   root = Tk()
   root.geometry("1200x1000+30+30")
   # width x height + x_offset + y_offset:
   T = Text(root, height=10, width=100)
   T.place(x=20, y=30)
   for i in range(40):
      T.insert(END, "This is line %d\n" % i)


   yscroll = Scrollbar(command=T.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
   T.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
   yscroll.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)

   root.mainloop()
```

The srollbar is on the window frame, is there a way I can move it inside and to the right edge of text area?

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: add tag, grammar

Answer (score 1):

There might be another way, but I would use the `ScrolledText` widget contained in `tkinter.scrolledtext`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledText

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x1000+30+30")
# width x height + x_offset + y_offset:
T = ScrolledText(root, height=10, width=100)
T.place(x=20, y=30)
for i in range(40):
    T.insert(END, "This is line %d\n" % i)

root.mainloop()
```

This automatically puts the scrollbar inside of the textbox.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976546/scrollbar-in-tkinter-inside-text-widget#41977458) I also got that you could use `place` instead of `pack` to position the scrollbar and then use `in_=T`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x1000+30+30")
# width x height + x_offset + y_offset:
T = Text(root, height=10, width=100)
T.place(x=20, y=30)
for i in range(40):
    T.insert(END, "This is line %d\n" % i)


yscroll = Scrollbar(command=T.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
yscroll.place(in_=T, relx=1.0, relheight=1.0, bordermode="outside")
T.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use place, but it's rarely the best solution.